# Very basic probability question.

Tags: probability

Let $b$ signify a boy and $g$ signify a girl. The sample space for fraternal ($F$) twins is $bb, bg, gb, gg$ with equal probability and the sample space for Identical ($I$) twins is $bb,gg,$ with equal probability. If $\Pr(F)=2/3$ and $\Pr(I)=1/3$ find the probability that the twins are both girls.

Now I am confused as to whether you calculate the probability as $\Pr(gg\cap F)+Pr(gg\cap I)$ or as $\Pr(gg|F)+\Pr(gg|I)$. Thank you.

Comment: The analysis begins thus: The children can be both girls in two disjoint ways: (i) they are fraternal twins and both girls or (ii) they are identical twins and both girls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula is $\Pr(gg \cap F) + \Pr(gg \cap I) = \Pr(gg|F)\Pr(F)+\Pr(gg|I)\Pr(I)$.

---

Just to be sure, let's suppose the formula was $\Pr(gg|F)+\Pr(gg|I)$.

Then, the probability of two girls would be $\Pr(gg|F)+\Pr(gg|I) = \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4} = \dfrac{3}{4}$.

Similarly, the probability of two boys would be $\Pr(bb|F)+\Pr(bb|I) = \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4} = \dfrac{3}{4}$.

So, the probability of two boys or two girls (disjoint events) would be $\dfrac{3}{4}+\dfrac{3}{4} = \dfrac{3}{2}$, which is absurd.